# How to economy games engine work?

Tags: game-engine

I was wondering how online strategy/economy game engines work. The aim is to understand how engines manage (nearly) real time calculation when a large number of players, mechanisms and resources are involved.

- I'm not trying to understand how functional economy mechanisms are build but rather how they are handled by whatever technology is behind it;
- How does the engine manages to compute and update different states (of resources, exchanges, etc...) at regular intervals;
- Is their one big clock computing every quantities at regular intervals ?
- Are their multi-thread / some kind of synchronisation mechanism for each player involved ?
- Finally what under-the-hood technologies are/can be involved in games like The Settlers Online for example ?

The aim here is to understand how a game engine can be architecture to handle big data in a complex mechanism that involves resources production, consumption and exchange when a large number (possibly infinite) number of players are involved.

Game examples:

- The settlers online
- Anno Online
- etc...

Comment: This could potentially be a very interesting question, but I think this question does need to be rewritten and clarified. What is the exact "economy" you speak of? you mean marketting? Can you give an example of a game you mean, because I'm not sure what you mean - describe your question to someone who has no idea what you're on about. That will help everyone :)

Comment: That's much better for me, cheers

Comment: Now let the Internet work its magic... ;-)

Comment: Question put on hold ? Whats that ?

Comment: And I was just about to post my answer :-(

Comment: Does that mean you can't answer ? Wow those guys are working against knowledge...

Comment: SO people think this question is too broad, you could try and rewrite it again and make the question specific to a certain game, such as Settlers online, and a certain aspect of that certain game. -- for example "how does the resources economy of Settlers Online keep in step with having thousands of players around the world simultaneously". I guess

Comment: I cant really rephrase because thats exactly what i want to know. I'm asking for general principles and which technologies are involved...so. Could you answer me privately ?

Comment: my answer is too long for comment :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83611/discussion-between-martin-and-romain-bruckert).